# Problems with resize on Expander WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resize, expander

Hi guys i'm using WPF with mvvm on a solution and i have an issue.
I have this object that i am using on a viewModel:

```
public class SuperCharacter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Character> Characters { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Character charactersExp;
    private const string currentCharacterExpandedString = "CurrentCharacterExp";
    public Character CurrentCharacterExpanded
    {
        get { return this.charactersExp; }
        set
        {
            this.charactersExp = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(currentCharacterExpandedString);
        }
    }

    public string CalcSize { get; set; }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {


        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And i have this view:

```
    Window.Resources>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="TrackPointUserSavedSearchDtoTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:Character}">
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBlock x:Name="caption" Margin="1" 
        Text="{Binding First}" MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="40" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DynamicUserSaveSearchesTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:Character}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TrackPointUserSavedSearchDtoTemplate    }"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="IconoTrackPointUSTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:SuperCharacter}">
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Expander Height="180" Margin="12,0,0,-127" >

                <Expander.Header>
                    <Binding Path="Name"></Binding>
                </Expander.Header>                   

                    <ListView Name="ProblemListView" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCharacterExpanded}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DynamicUserSaveSearchesTemplate}" Panel.ZIndex="20">
                    </ListView>                       
            </Expander>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DynamicTrackPointUSTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:SuperCharacter}" >
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconoTrackPointUSTemplate    }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="42"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Entitty's TrackPoint list:" Margin="12,5,76,9" Name="labelName" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SuperCharacters}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSuperCharacterExpanded}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DynamicTrackPointUSTemplate}">
    </ListView>
<Grid/>
```

The problem is when i expand the Expander the elements from the Listview call ProblemListView are below to next expander.

I like to know how can i make this expander list look correct? if i expand an expander the problemListView show correctly.

Just remember that the list is dynamic and can have different numbers of elements

Comment: Would it be possible to add some pictures of the problem?

Comment: Do you need a `ScrollViewer` inside each expander? Or is that meant to be only for the outer `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think setting `Grid.Row="2"` for the `ScrollViewer` in your `DataTemplate` doesn't make much sense. Second, the `margin` of your `Expander` is causing trouble, I don't quite get why you are setting a that bottom margin (-127).

You need to specify a `Height` for your `ScrollViewer`, otherwise the grid row will just expand as the `ListView` grows.

Try these changes to the `IconoTrackPointUSTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IconoTrackPointUSTemplate" DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication1:SuperCharacter}">
    <ScrollViewer Height="50" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Expander Margin="12,0,0,0" Header="{Binding Name}">
            <ListView Name="ProblemListView" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCharacterExpanded}" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DynamicUserSaveSearchesTemplate}" 
                        Panel.ZIndex="20" />
        </Expander>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

Just as a tip, note how I changed the binding of the expander header, you can save quite some space doing the inline:

```
Header="{Binding Name}"
```